# fromURL Images Not Showing When Exporting

Tags: fabricjs

I add several images using fromURL, all from external sites(not sure if that has anything to do with the issues):

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('<zillow listing image URL>', function (img) {
...scaleToHeight stuff...
...clipPath stuff to do some masking...
canvas.add(img);
});
```

Output to PNG. Had to use this workaround to get around a chrome frame issue with jsPDF

```
function debugBase64 (base64URL) {
var win = window.open();
win.document.write('<iframe src="' + base64URL + '" frameborder="0" style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}

debugBase64(canvas.toDataURL('png'));
```

....I have tried this PNG export and a few others and it's always the same thing. All of the text and basic shapes show up great, but never the images that I brought in with fromURL. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were there any errors in the console?  There's a good chance that your canvas was "tainted" by the external URLs.  In that case you just need to add `{ crossOrigin: 'anonymous'}` as a third argument to the `fromURL` function.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am actually including that when the new fabric instance is being created. Also, come to find out, it's not even showing the image in the JSON when I export it.

....and no, there are no console errors.

Comment: Do you have a working example you could link?

Comment: I don't have a live, working example unfortunately. This is all in a local environment at this point. I am aware of the console error you are talking about as I have seen references to it in my research and I don't see that in my console. I thought initially that this may be an issue with the toDataURL method, but since my Image.FromURL objects don't even show up in the JSON export this leads me to believe it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

I am implementing this in Vue. I put most everything initially in 'mounted' and was just putting 'console.log(canvas.toJSON());' at the end of the section. Apparently this was still affected by racing, though. Because when I instead added a button to log the JSON it included the image objects as well.